# Android Material default colors

Tags: android, colors, material-design, android-cardview

I want to have colors for specific card states. I want to be able to reset it to its default.

Where can I find the default material colors from Android? Especally of the Android CardView.

Thanks for help.

Edit:

The Cards have an backgroundcolor (not the images) which is not white. Which color is this?
Or is there any method to reset the Backgroundcolor of View-Elements?

[image: Sample of Cards]

Sry for bad english.

Comment: i don't fully understand your issue so this is a guess.. http://www.materialpalette.com/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution: `#fafafa`

It's the Background colour that Google used on the website hakkikonu posted.

Edit:

Maybe it changed over time. Updated answer (thanks to [arts777](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497132/arts777))

Comment: Hm, but this guide https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-themes says that default BG color is #fafafa

Answer (score 11):

https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-themes link describes all of your question. Also you can see more notes about material design.

Comment: Maybe i´m stupid, but i can´t find the default cardview background color

Comment: @R00st3r It states that the card (and dialog) background color should be #FFFFFF for light themes and #424242 for dark themes.  It's at the bottom under "Themes".

Answer (score 5):

If you're worried that this color will change over time and you'd like to be up to date if and when Google changes it, you can use `?android:colorBackground`.

As of July 2017, it is still `#FAFAFA`